# App Loaded with white screen when i run Cordova application in Android device?

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2013, hybrid-mobile-app, apache-cordova

I have developed Mobile application using Visual Studio 2013(Apache-cordova). When i run app on ripple emulator its working fine.when i start run into device its showing blank screen instead of login screen.Same issue already i had faced when i run my first application that time i missed package the android app my problem was solved.key store also i updated now still am getting this issue.How can i solve this issue.can anyone help me?

```js
'use strict';
angular.module('app')
    .run(
        [
            '$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
            function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
                $rootScope.$state = $state;
                $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
            }
        ]
    )
    .config(
        [
            '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
            function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
                //$urlRouterProvider
                //.otherwise('/app/dashboard');
            
                $urlRouterProvider
                    .otherwise('/login');
                $stateProvider
                    .state('app', {
                        abstract: true,
                        url: '/app',
                        templateUrl: 'views/layout.html'
                    })

])
            .state('login', {
                    url: '/login',
                    templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
                    ncyBreadcrumb: {
                        label: 'Login'
                    },
                    resolve: {
                        deps: [
                            '$ocLazyLoad',
                            function($ocLazyLoad) {
                                return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                                    serie: true,
                                    files: [
                                       'app/controllers/loginredirecttoreg.js',
                                       'app/services/accountdetailservices.js'                                        
                                    ]
                                });
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                })
```

Comment: where did u declared login state?

Comment: Added Login state now. Please Check and reply.

Comment: I Fix the White Screen Issue.I have included href="http://....js" files directly.when i removed these links from index.html my problem was solved.

Comment: wow thats really great :-)

Comment: @divya can you please elaborate on the solution?

Comment: you check your index page if you included https anywhere please replace it to http.and generete key pair and package your app. for your reference first.https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/